# Can't get ethernet connection to work with 'Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)' on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, ethernet

I am trying to get ethernet connection to work on a hp compaq 8200 elite sff computer, but with no success so far.

When i plug in an ethernet cable, the network icon starts the searching animation, but the computer will never get assigned an IP-address. The ethernet cable is comming from a cisco switch, that's linked to an 802.1x network, but booting from the same media using same cable on another computer(another driver), works fine.

I have tried the following commands:

lspci | grep Ethernet

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
enter code here
```

lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1495]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
```

ethtool -i eth0

```
driver: e1000e
version: 3.2.4.2-NAPI
firmware-version: 0.13-4
bus-info: 0000:00:19.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

According to 'dmesg | grep eth0', the following lines appears, when i pull out the ethernet cable, and plug it back in:

```
eth0 NIC Link is Down
eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow control: None
0000:00:19.0 eth0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
```

According to 'ifconfig', the eth0 doesn't get any ip-address.

I have also tried the following commands, which didn't work:

- sudo modprobe -r e1000e; sudo modprobe e1000e
- sudo service network-manager restart
- sudo dhclient eth0
- sudo ifconfig eth0 down; sudo ifconfig eth0 up

Comment: try `sudo dhclient eth0` or
`sudo ifconfig eth0 down` and then `sudo ifconfig eth0 up`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` and then `sudo ifconfig eth0 up` turned off the "searching animation" and then on again, but still no Ip-address assigned/still no connection.


`sudo dhclient eth0` didn't work either, but it took forever to be executed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` terminal command.